# Pull GitHub Xcode project - gRPC target integrity error

Tags: xcode, github, podfile

I have an Xcode project that I use GitHub to manage between a few different computers. I use pod files for Firebase and a few other libraries. I recently made a change in a UserData file, and it was added to the repository. Now when I pull on another machine, I have the following errors

[image]

I've tried to delete the added user data and cloning the project over, but these errors persist. I can only assume that frameworks like gRPC and Protobuf are pointing to a file path that is local to my other machine, but I'm not sure how to redirect/reset the paths.

Comment: Up-voted, but maybe I'm wrong. (1) Why the Swift tag? Everything you state makes it feel like it shouldn't be. Should I remove that tag? (2) What version of Xcode? It might matter, as I've seen quite a few changes between version 9 and 8 - and who knows about dot releases.